# jq recursion of unknown levels between two select() filters

Tags: jq

given a variable nested json, I would like to filter based on two select functions and return an array of values matching a key.

Is it possible when the recursion between say "dog" and "breed" is unknown and different for multiple branches, but "breed is always a child/grandchild of "dog" in the same json?

I have tried using "objects as a bridge but this does not return a result

```
//should return ["one","two"]
// tried ....
jq '.. | select(.dog?) | select(.breed?) | .breed' myfile.json 
jq '.. | select(.dog?) | objects | select(.breed?) | .breed' myfile.json
jq '.. | objects | select(.dog?) | select(.breed?) | .breed' myfile.json
jq '.. | objects | select(.dog?) | objects | select(.breed?) | .breed' myfile.json


{
"alpha": {
    "this": {
        "dog": {
            "breed": "one",
            "colors": {
                "eyes": "blue"
            }
        }

    }
},
"beta": {
    "dog": {
        "crazy": {
            "world": {
                "breed": "two",
                "colors": {
                    "eyes": "blue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"charlie": {
    "format": {
        "bird": {
            "boat": {
                "breed": "three",
                "colors": {
                    "eyes": "blue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: //should return ["one","two"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `path` built-in to get root to leaf paths of all the elements in the JSON structure and filter those containing the last path as `breed` and contains `dog` somewhere along. Then use `getpath/1` to obtain the value at the obtained path.

```
[ getpath(paths | select(.[-1] == "breed" and index("dog"))) ]
```

[jqplay - Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/RS27edVFvPr)

Comment: excellent, I had tried putting `getpath(paths` inside the `select()` rather than on the outside and when I got an error thought I was on the wrong track (path?)

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
[.. | objects | .dog | .. | objects | .breed // empty]
```

Or also:

```
[.. | .dog? | .. | .breed? // empty]
```